# Implement print dialog in my code

Tags: c#, wpf, printdialog

I've been trying to solve this myself, but I haven't figured it out yet. I want to open a print dialog window when I'm pressing the `btn_print` button. I've called out one line I assume is not needed anymore as this is defining the size of the printed page.

Could anyone look at my code and tell me what I could do?

```
private void btn_print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: well, what is not working?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It is working @roryap, but this is just printing on the default printer without opening the print dialog. I want to add that feature to this code.

Comment: Did you try googling it?  It's a little too broad a question for this site.

Comment: @roryap, yes I have, and I've tried to use the PrintDialog class with no luck. I think I'll try more and try to come with a code that will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
//pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);

System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog p = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
p.Document = pd;
if (p.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    pd.Print();
```

Comment: This didn't work @J.H. . The namespace System.Windows.Forms does not exist and probalby belongs to Windows Forms? I removed the namespace in the code and I get an error that printdialog does not contain a definition for document and 'bool?' does not contain a definition for OK.

Comment: Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms and it will work.

Comment: It sure did! I think I was missing that reference when I tried out other things. Thank a lot @J.H.!